# I have a problem reading string one after the other

Tags: c

I could able to read the first string (name) and after reading I couldn't able to enter the value for the second string (dept).
I get output in this way:

No of students : 12

Student Name?
Prince Daniel
Department? 
Age?

```
struct student{
    char name[100],dept[3];
    int age;
};

void printBook(struct book *);
void populateBook(struct book*);
int main(){

   struct student s_arr[12];
   int n = sizeof(s_arr)/sizeof(s_arr[0]);
   printf("No of students : %d\n",n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fillDetails(&s_arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void fillDetails(struct student *temp){
    printf("Student Name?\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",temp->name);
    printf("Department? \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",temp->dept);
    printf("Age?\n");
    scanf("%d",&temp->age);
}
```

Comment: Note that `%[^\n]s` isn't a valid format. It inputs a string and then matches an `'s'`. It should be `%[^\n]`. Also that newline remains in the buffer, so you need a space in front of the format spec to cause it to be filtered out. So `" %[^\n]"`. You also need to restrict the input string lengths to `" %99[^\n]"` and `" %2[^\n]"`. Is 2 characters enough for the department?

Comment: ... if someone enters 3 characters for the department it all goes wrong, and the third character + newline are presented to the input for `age` which will block it if it is an alphabet character. I suggest using `fgets` with a generous string length for all inputs and processing each string input with `sscanf`. Also always check the return value from `scanf` function family (number of items processed). Input is tricky, `scanf` very tricky. You can easily spend more time on a solid user interface than on the problem itself.

Comment: Strictly, saying that `%[^\n]s` isn't a valid format is not correct. It certainly isn't a useful format, but it is 'valid' in the sense that it has a meaning. It will be interpreted by `scanf()` et al "correctly", but the correct interpretation isn't what most novices expect. With no length limit on the `%[^\n]` part (not `%99[^\n]`, for example), then the `s` is guaranteed to fail to match the newline left by the scan set. With a length limit (`%4[^\n]`), given input `jokes`, it would read `joke` into the string and the `s` would match the scan pattern. But that isn't a plausible use!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler true, but `%[^\n]s` isn't ***a*** format, but a mistaken hybrid of `%s` and `%[\n]` and is actually **two** formats. The first `%[^\n]` matches a sequence of characters, the second `s` matches that letter.

Comment: It works when I add " %[^\n]", Why is it so?

Comment: It is only a hybrid in the minds of novice C programmers — those who have not yet been burned by the fact that a scan set is not a modifier for `%s`.  It is one part conversion specification (`%[^\n]`) and one part literal match (`s`).  I know you know; it is pedanticism on my part.  I gave your comment an up-vote (I agree enough to do that).  But strictly…

Comment: Most format specifiers automatically filter out leading whitespace, which includes newlines. But `%c` and `%[]` do not. Placing a space in front instructs `scanf` to filter whitespace in these cases too. In the same way that the mistaken `s` matches an actual 's', this space match *any amount of* whitespace.

Comment: @PrinceDaniel — because the leading space in the format skips over white space (blanks, tabs _and_ newlines), skipping over the newline left behind by the previous `%[^\n]` scan set conversion specification.  Most conversion specifiers skip leading space automatically.  There are three that don't: `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), and `%n`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, there is no harm in a dialog for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for helping me out with this. Appreciate it!

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for helping me out with this. Appreciate it!

Comment: I hope you have enough information to get it all working now.

Comment: please post the definition of: `struct book`